# R divide each column in dataframe by last row value

Tags: r

I have a dataframe and am trying to divide each column in dataframe by last row value:

```
A <- c(1:10)
B <- c(2:11)
C <- c(3:12)

df1 <- data.frame(A,B,C)


df2 <- df1/df1[10,]
```

However I get an error.
I would be grateful to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`data.frames` aren't made for those kinds of operations.

```
 data.frame(lapply(df1, function(X) X/X[10]))
```

Should do the trick. Or use a matrix instead.

```
df1 = as.matrix(df1)

> t(t(df1)/df1[10,])
        A         B         C
 [1,] 0.1 0.1818182 0.2500000
 [2,] 0.2 0.2727273 0.3333333
 [3,] 0.3 0.3636364 0.4166667
 [4,] 0.4 0.4545455 0.5000000
 [5,] 0.5 0.5454545 0.5833333
 [6,] 0.6 0.6363636 0.6666667
 [7,] 0.7 0.7272727 0.7500000
 [8,] 0.8 0.8181818 0.8333333
 [9,] 0.9 0.9090909 0.9166667
[10,] 1.0 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Comment: Also, `sweep(mat,2,mat[10,],\`/\`)`

Answer (score 7):

Dividing by `c(df[10,])` works, as well, such as:

`df1/c(df1[10,])`

Comment: Doesn't yield correct results. `unlist(df1[10,])` is applied to each column separately.

Comment: @SeñorO Yep, I wasn't paying enough attention past the first row.  Edited.

Answer (score 3):

```
> df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) x/tail(x,1) )
> df1
     A         B         C
1  0.1 0.1818182 0.2500000
2  0.2 0.2727273 0.3333333
3  0.3 0.3636364 0.4166667
4  0.4 0.4545455 0.5000000
5  0.5 0.5454545 0.5833333
6  0.6 0.6363636 0.6666667
7  0.7 0.7272727 0.7500000
8  0.8 0.8181818 0.8333333
9  0.9 0.9090909 0.9166667
10 1.0 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

This is somewhat more painful but might be faster in bigger data situations:

```
 data.matrix(df1) / rep( unlist(df1[10,]), each=nrow(df1) )
```

Frank is partly correct (and I was close with one of my earlier failed attempts to use sweep:

```
 sweep(df1, 2, unlist(df1[10, ]),  "/")
```

Comment: The first one can be written nicely as `df1[] <- Map("/", df1, tail(df1, 1))`

Comment: Nice. I can see why hat works after a bit of thought. I tried doing it with `sweep`, but I've never grokked `sweep`.

Comment: I think you can only `sweep` a matrix, but the OP should be using a matrix anyway if this operation (dividing by the last column) is valid, since all cols are numeric... `sweep(mat,2,mat[10,],`/`)` here

Comment: I just discovered that you can sweep a data.frame, but the error I was causing was by using a single row data.frame as the third argument "statitistic".

Answer (score 0):

```
sapply(names(df1),function(x)df1[,x]/df1[nrow(df1),x])
        A         B         C
 [1,] 0.1 0.1818182 0.2500000
 [2,] 0.2 0.2727273 0.3333333
 [3,] 0.3 0.3636364 0.4166667
 [4,] 0.4 0.4545455 0.5000000
 [5,] 0.5 0.5454545 0.5833333
 [6,] 0.6 0.6363636 0.6666667
 [7,] 0.7 0.7272727 0.7500000
 [8,] 0.8 0.8181818 0.8333333
 [9,] 0.9 0.9090909 0.9166667
[10,] 1.0 1.0000000 1.0000000
```